create a query with string variable using python gql and psycopg2
Let's say Ia have the following string to be passed as query for an API call using python:
import psycopg2
from gql import Client, gql
from gql.transport.requests import RequestsHTTPTransport
from datetime import datetime

start_year = str(datetime.now().year -4) 
end_year = str(datetime.now().year)
query_str = """
query events{
api_version
public_DB(
filters: {
iso: ["Nation1","Nation2","Nation3"]
from: 2020,
to: 2024,
classif: ["car","bus","train",]
include_hist: true
}
) {
total_available
info {
timestamp
filters
cursor
}
data {
disno
iso
start_year
start_month
start_day
end_year
end_month
end_day
type
subtype
entry_date
last_update
}
}
}
"""

query = gql(query_str)


transport = RequestsHTTPTransport(
url='https://api.open_DB.it/v1',
headers={'Authorization': api_key},
use_json=True,
)
# Create a GraphQL client using the defined transport
client = Client(transport=transport, fetch_schema_from_transport=True)
# Execute the query
response = client.execute(query)


What I would like to do is to pass two variables string (start_year, end_year) for the start year (2020) and the end year (2024) so that I can change them at the beginning of the code


This has nothing to do with psycopg2, so I am removing that tag. 2) The docs are the place to start, see Using variables.


I’m voting to close this question because of lack of basic research.

I did my research and could not find an appropriate solution. By the way, I solved the problem even without using the GqL library using a string replace
